# "StopUpdatingLocation" is called but GPS Arrow doesnt disappear

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I don´t understand why the gray gps arrow don´t disappear after stopUpdatingLocation is called. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    if (self.locationManager == nil)
    {
    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init]autorelease];
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    }
    CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    g_lat = coordinate.latitude;
    g_lng = coordinate.longitude;


    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

And here ist my didUpdateLocation:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:  (CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
    NSLog(@"Core location has a position.");

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [newLocation coordinate];

    global_lat = coordinate.latitude;
    global_lng = coordinate.longitude;

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    }

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"Core location can't get a fix.");
}
```

I also checked if any other app is using GPS!
After 20 minutes the Arrow is still there....
Thanks for help!

***EDIT:***

I think i missed something very important, on my first view after the App is started there is a Google Map! This is my Code:

```
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:g_lat
                                                            longitude:g_lng
                                                                 zoom:15];



    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0f, 160.0f, 320.0f, 100)
                                     camera:camera];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.trafficEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
    [self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setCamera:camera];

    [self.containerView addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Is it possible that the google map is updating all the time? If Yes, how can i stop that?

Comment: I'm just curious, what's the point of this: `NSLog(@"%@", @"Core location can't get a fix.");`You can simply write: `NSLog(@"Core location can't get a fix.");` There is no need for arguments.

Comment: Yes you are right, i changed something and forgot to delete the argument part :)

Comment: Regarding the google map: do you turn off the `myLocationEnabled`  field when you push the new view controller? If not, then that can keep the GPS running. You can try it by not starting the GPS on the next view controller. If the GPS stays on, then the map is holding it.

Comment: That was the problem, now the arrow disappears :). I would like to accept this as the right answer, but it seems not possible because its a comment?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can accept that instead of the comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the google map: do you turn off the `myLocationEnabled` field when you push the new view controller? If not, then that can keep the GPS running. You can try it by not starting the GPS on the next view controller. If the GPS stays on, then the map is holding it.

Side note: This can be part of the normal operation. If your app stops receiving the location updates, then you are doing fine. iOS is doing lots of optimizations and leaving the GPS on for some time is probably part of this. During testing I saw that the arrow usually stays on for a while even if the app is killed from XCode.

Comment: Yes it stopped updating. So its normal that the arrow is still there after 20 minutes??

Comment: Oh, I missed that. 20 minutes is not negligible. For me it's less than a minute, I suppose. At least I haven't seen it stay there for much longer.

Comment: Try to disallow all other applications from using the location services: Settings->Privacy->Location Services and turn off all apps. You may even reboot the device at this point to make sure it's clean. Then rerun your app and include a line to release the location manager when you stop the location updates. If you need it again, simply create a new one.